# Can't Build Project Artifact (mvn clean install)

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, artifactory

I'm trying to build the project artifact and have updated my settings.xml file with the format from my artifactory maven-amt-prereleases and also inputting my API key for the password, but am getting the errors when trying command "mvn clean install":

[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' of POM myproject(C:\Users...pom.xml) points at myproject instead of boot-starter-parent, please verify your project structure @ line 14, column 10
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for myproject: Could not transfer artifact boot-starter-parent:pom:6.4.0 from/to central (https://artifactory...-amt-prereleases): status code: 401, reason phrase:  (401) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 14, column 10
@
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project myproject(C:\Users\A733238\ap141699-cde-kafka-data-streaming\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for myproject: Could not transfer artifact boot-starter-parent:pom:6.4.0 from/to central (https://artifac...maven-amt-prereleases): status code: 401, reason phrase:  (401) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 14, column 10 -> [Help 2]

Answer (score 0):

The status code 401 indicates an authentication issue. It seems like the generated settings.xml file had some issues in terms of credentials configuration. Here is the sample snippet for your reference.

```
<servers>
<server>
  <username>testuser</username>
  <password>testPass@1</password>
  <id>central</id>
</server>
<server>
  <username>testuser</username>
  <password>testPass@1</password>
  <id>snapshots</id>
</server>
```

To generate settings.xml with username and API Key/encrypted password, click on "Set Me UP" and select the Maven repository. Pass the credential and click on the "Download snippet" option. By default, Artifactory won't show those values in UI due to security reasons. Kindly watch JFrog's [screencast video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGXrPz9wwOY&t=206s) on setting up Maven repositories for more details.